# How can i assign value to a global variable in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I met a problem recently: How can i assign value to a global variable?

when i try to return a, i found that is undefined, and the "value" i wanna to assign to it is not undefined.

my code is like this:

```
module.exports = function (jsonStr) {
    var a;
    request(main_url, function(error, response, html) { 
        if(!error) {
           ...
           request(sub_url, function(error, response, html) { 
               if(!error) {
                  ...
                  a = value;
                  ...
               }
           }
         }    
    } 
    return a;   
});
```

Comment: replace "var a" with "". but, btter, don't use globals; tack the stuff onto `exports` as needed.

Comment: That is because `a = value` gets executed asynchronously (the assignment happens **after** your function on `module.exports` finishes execution). What you should do is have a callback on your function that has `a` as an argument. (For example, `function(jsonStr, callback)`)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407269/why-cant-i-see-this-json-in-the-console

Comment: @JCOC611 Omg, after? ah, that's why, i will check my logic again. Thank you !

Comment: @JCOC611 sorry, i tried, but i still failed to return a, i was totally confused about how to return it. T.T can u help me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem there is that your `request` function is asynchronous, and then, the `return a` statement will occur before you set `a = value`.

One way to achieve what you want is by using [the `asyncawait` library](https://github.com/yortus/asyncawait), something like:

```
module.exports = async(function (jsonStr) {
    var a;
    var sub_url = await(request(main_url));
    a = await(request(sub_url));
    return a; 
});
```

Take a look at [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron).